# llamar variable desde otro componente - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

tengo una variable en el componente1 pero necesito llamar esa variable en el componente2 y no he logrado hacerlo, este es el codigo que tengo:

componente1:

```js
import React from 'react'

function Componente1() {

    global.url_login='https://www.deportes.mipagina.com/api/usuarios/';
    
    return (
        <div>        
        </div>
    )
}
export default Componente1
```

componente2 :

```js
import React from 'react'
import Componente1 from './Componente1'

console.log("url" + global.url_login);

function Componente2() {
   
    return (
        <div>   
        
        </div>
    )
}
export default Componente2
```

Comment: Considera utilizar [context](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) o [redux](https://es.redux.js.org/) para tu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera tradicional de settear un atributo estático a una funciona es la siguiente

```js
// Mostramos el mensaje que contiene el atributo msg de la func App
const App = () => console.log(App.msg)
// Setteamos el atributo "estático"
App.msg = "Hola este es un mensaje"
// Llamamos a la función
App()
```

Entonces en tu componente lo declaras de la siguiente forma.

```
function Componente1() {
  return <div>Hola!</div>;
}
// Aquí setteas la propiedad.
Componente1.global = {
  url_login: "https://www.deportes.mipagina.com/api/usuarios/"
};

export default Componente1;
```

Y para acceder a el, simplemente tienes que poner el nombre de la función importada y el atributo al que quieres acceder.

```
import Componente1 from './Componente1'
console.log(Componente1.global.url_login);
```